# ipython function to send last command to script

Tags: ipython

Is there a way I can send my last ipython command to a script?

Desired usage would be something like:

```
$ tail script.py
...

[1] my_command = 0
[2] %saveLastCmd script.py  # equivalent to $ echo <command> >> script.py

$ tail script.py
....
my_command = 0

[1] my_command = 1
[2] %saveLastCmd script.py  # equivalent to $ echo <command> >> script.py

$ tail script.py
....
my_command = 0
my_command = 1
```

Comment: Reading through the ipython magic functions and typing my question into google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Save the contents of a cell or output to a .py file

def foo(): print('bar')
foo()

# -f forces overwrite of output file, -a appends to file

%save -f -a 'foo_in' _ih[-1]
```

Comment: You can change the `-1` index to save any cell you'd like. using `%save 'foo' _[-1]` should get you the last output as well.

Comment: Can I use this to append to an exiting script like in my example?